# Should GET requests be allowed to trigger exceptions?

Tags: java, rest, exception

I am developing a rest server. I am trying to add html injection check(sanitation) for all 4 actions.
On error, I am planning to throw exception. I think Post, Put actions can throw exceptions but no sure if the GET and DELETE action can throw exception(from design perspective).
The design docs requires return empty if the inputs contain sql/html injections. Throwing exceptions from GET action sounds wired.
Thanks.

Comment: Any method can throw an exception, if there's a reason for it.

Comment: `GET` should not be submitting data to the server, so where would "HTML injection" happen? Rather than trying to *detect* SQL injection, I'd say you should sanitize your input (query params, etc.).

Comment: Returning `false` is probably better than throwing an exception.

Comment: When we are doing pagination, the GUI needs to pass information for the filter. So GET will pass data to server.

Comment: Yes, passing a query param can cause SQL injection. That's valid and you should sanitize the input from the client. That is not the same as detecting, and I don't see how HTML injection would occur, so it's not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With REST you should be returning correct Http status codes, not throwing exceptions.

Comment: I expect he's using a JAX-RS framework where thrown exceptions become proper HTTP responses.

Comment: Hopefully he will comment and let us know :) Either way, I assume there is some sort of exception mapping so that a user does not receive 500 errors all the time

Comment: I think Leon is right, there is no exception for rest, only the error.Great! Thanks.